# Extending Visual Studio getting ProjectItem or IVsHierarchy based on file path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to build an extension for Visual Studio 2017, the idea is to automatically include files that are created in a certain folder on disk (using a FileSystemWatcher), any changes to folder names and/or filenames should also be reflected (included) i the Project.

I've looked around for an existing extension without any luck.

After working on this for a while I'm quite close to a solution but the current approach that I have for removing items from the Solution Explorer when file/foldernames are changed/deleted does not scale when the solution is bigger (have many files in it). My current approach is to use the root IVsHierarchy and process it recursively and then find a file/folder based on the "canonicalName". This means that I have to scan the solution each time i need to find a folder. The solution is inspired by this code https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014007.aspx

I started out with using Project.ProjectItems but this collection would sometimes just contain a "root" folder ie with these files on disk

```
/Test/MyFile.txt
/Test/Folder1
/Test/Folder2
/Test/Folder3
```

The only ProjectItem that I could find was /Test/, this does not work if I need to remove /Test/Folder1 ie. The approach with IVsHierarchy gave me all the folder and the implementation works but are slow.

So, my question:

Is there a way to get a reference to a ProjectItem based on the full path of the file/folder on disk? So that I don't have to iterate over all items in the solution to find my ProjectItem and slow down everything. It would also work with a reference to a IVsHierarchy that I can use to get the ProjectItem.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._solution.findprojectitem?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Comment: Thanks Carlos! But this would but unfortunately return a folder in the case that I'm. When I need to delete /Test/Folder1/ This folder is not found, the only "ProjectItem", the only ProjectItem that can be found at that stage is /Test/ which I don't want to remove since I want to keep Folder2 and Folder3. But the approach that you are suggesting works well with actual files like /Test/Folder1/myFile.txt.